# Не могу правильно вывести полученные числа из массива

Tags: c++, массивы

Доброго времени суток. У меня такое задание "Есть массив с любым кол-вом чисел ( у меня их 50) и нужно вывести числа массива которые %3 потом которые %7 и которые %9( то есть не для одного числа выполняется условие %3 %7 и %9, а пройтись по всему массиву и вывести сначала числа которые  %3 потом на %7 и на %9) и в конце вывести числа которые не подходят под данные условия.
Это я сделал и вот он код:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int arr[50];
cout<<"Created Array :"<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<51;i++){
   arr[i]=i;
    cout<<"|"<<i;
    }
cout<<endl;
cout<<endl;
cout<<"Numbers that can be devided on 3 :"<<endl;
for(int i=0;i<51;i++){
   if(i%3==0)
       cout<<"|"<<i;
   }
   cout<<endl;
cout<<endl;
cout<<"Numbers that can be devided on 7 :"<<endl;
for(int i=0;i<51;i++){
    if(i%7==0)
        cout<<"|"<<i;
}
cout<<endl;
cout<<endl;

cout<<"Numbers that can be devided on 9 :"<<endl;
for(int i=0;i<51;i++){
    if(i%9==0)
        cout<<"|"<<i;
}
cout<<endl;
cout<<endl;
cout<<"Numbers that can`t be devided on 3 or 7 or 9 :"<<endl;
for(int i=0;i<51;i++){
    if(i%9!=0 && i%7!=0 && i%3!=0)
        cout<<"|"<<i;
}
}
```

По коду ясно что мне выводит числа массива, которые подходят под условие, в строчку. Итого у меня 4 строчки.
Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы эти 4 строчки объединились в одну, то есть будет : 0 3 6 9...(числа которые делятся на 3) потом 0 7 14 21.. потом 0 9 18 27.. и потом числа которые не подходят под условия 1 2 4 5 ... , что собственно у меня и не выходит и поэтому эта тема здесь.
Прошу прощения за слишком много букв.

Comment: А endl по вашему это что?

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(){
int arr[50];
cout<<"Created Array :"<<endl;
for(int i=0;i<51;i++){
  arr[i]=i;
  cout<<"|"<<i;
}
cout<<endl;
cout<<endl;
cout<<"Numbers that can be devided on 3 :"<<endl;
for(int i=0;i<51;i++){
if(i%3==0)
    cout<<"|"<<i;
}
//cout<<endl;
//cout<<endl;
//cout<<"Numbers that can be devided on 7 :"<<endl;  зачем перемещать каретку, если тебе нужно вывести все в строчку ?
for(int i=0;i<51;i++){
if(i%7==0)
    cout<<"|"<<i;
}
//cout<<endl;
//cout<<endl;
//cout<<"Numbers that can be devided on 9 :"<<endl;  зачем перемещать каретку, если тебе нужно вывести все в строчку ?
for(int i=0;i<51;i++){
if(i%9==0)
    cout<<"|"<<i;
}
//cout<<endl;
//cout<<endl;
//cout<<"Numbers that can`t be devided on 3 or 7 or 9 :"<<endl; зачем перемещать каретку, если тебе нужно вывести все в строчку ?
for(int i=0;i<51;i++){
  if(i%9!=0 && i%7!=0 && i%3!=0)
    cout<<"|"<<i;
}
```

}

Если не понятно, то можешь просто завести массив(проще вектор) резутальтата и в него складывать числа, а потом его вывести.